# How to convert a symbolic expression to MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

I have a complicated equation I can't seem to solve elegantly, so I want to use the symbolic solver and then just paste the result into my code.  The variables look like this kind of thing:

```
C=sym('C',[3,3]);
```

Which results in matrix entries that look like C_1_2, etc.

I can't seem to find an easy way to convert the result into the form C(1,2), which I could actually paste into MATLAB code.  Is there a way to do this without manually searching and replacing every possible index combination?

Comment: On la related note, see the [`latex`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html) function; alhtough it doesn't do what you want here

Answer (score 1):

You can use MATLAB to clean it up as a string and then paste into code.

```
newcodestring = regexprep(oldcodestring, 'C_(\d*)_(\d*)', 'C($1,$2)');
```